# PQexecParams failure using single quotes

Tags: c++, sql, libpq

I'm trying to insert into my SQL database using libpq with the following code:

```
void func(PGconn *conn)
{
    const char * params[2] = { "1", "\'POINT(0 0)\'" };
    res = PQexecParams(conn,
        "INSERT INTO drive_test_point (id, geom) VALUES ($1, ST_GeomFromText($2, 900913));",
        2,
        NULL,
        paramValues,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        1);

    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "INSERT failed: %s\n", PQerrorMessage(conn));
            PQclear(res);
    }
}
```

Output:

INSERT failed: ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  You must specify a valid OGC WKT geometry type such as POINT, LINESTRING or POLYGON

I think something is fishy with my single quotes around POINT(0 0). Can some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ST_MakePoint and pass in its parameters as coordinates. To wit:

> const char * params[2] = { "1", "0", "0" };
>
> res = PQexecParams(conn, "INSERT INTO drive_test_point (id, geom) VALUES ($1, ST_Point($2, $3))", NULL, 3, NULL, NULL, 0);

Hope that helps, albeit 7 years late.